# How to close Android Chrome password save popup with appium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, appium, remotewebdriver

How can I close the password save popup using C# webdriver with appium on android device?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I'm using appium with C# webdriver. Tried with the following:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("android.widget.ImageButton"));
```

and

```
driver.FindElementByName("Close").Click();
```

but the popup is not closing.
Tests are executed on a real device.

Here is the initialization code:

```
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability("device", "Android");
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Windows");
capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["deviceName"]);

capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["platformName"]);

capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["platformVersion"]);
capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appPackage"]);
capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appActivity"]);

driver = new AndroidDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
```

Comment: @Gaurav: tried both versions but I'm still not able to close the popup (closing button or never button or not identified). Do you have any other suggestion? Is there a way to disable password reminder using some capability?

Comment: @Suman I'm still not able to click on buttons. Do you have another suggestion? I've added some code to see what capabilities are set. I can only interact with elements from Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this as follows:

> Open the Settings app. Go to System>Language & Input, and expand the
>   Advanced settings  at the bottom. Tap Autofill Service.
>
> On the Autofill service, select ‘None’.

(reference: [ref](https://www.addictivetips.com/android/google-autofill-settings-for-apps-android/))

Comment: Thank you! This is the best answer because after you set this parameter, you shouldn't care about all this windows during the tests :)

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath 
`wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='Never']")).click();`
You can use any attribute such as resource-id, text, content-desc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageButton' and @name='Close']");

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Example:

While using protractor through appium on the android device I was able to remove the popup box from google chrome by passing the following into chromeOptions:

```
        'chromeOptions': {
            args: ['--disable-infobars']}
```

Passing this removed the exact popup you have mentioned.